# Setting basic cookie and alert with cookie value

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set a basic cookie. I've left the alert in so I can see if I'm successfully doing so. I want to store the end of the current url. For example, I want to store the MWFhUDfYpc9JYWmyapBDZvVYEz9rkMK6wSGZX4s. from http://www.example.com/index.php?cid=MWFhUDfYpc9JYWmyapBDZvVYEz9rkMK6wSGZX4s.

I've successfully set the cookie as the url on load, but can't get further.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function WriteCookie()
{
   cookievalue= window.location + ";";
   document.cookie="name=" + cookievalue;
   alert( cookievalue );
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to activate the window.location which returns the entire path of the current page. This is fine, but it will load the entire string `http://www.example.com/index.php?cid=MWFhUDfYpc9JYWmyapBDZvVYEz9rkMK6wSGZX4s` rather than just `MWFhUDfYpc9JYWmyapBDZvVYEz9rkMK6wSGZX4s`. And finally, if your only storing 1 key in your cookie, you do not need a semi-colon at the end of the document.cookie string.

Example jsfiddle: 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/technologrich/8q5RP/1/)

Here is a revised code, with some error handling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
WriteCookie();
function WriteCookie() {
    try {
        var splt = window.location.split("=");
        document.cookie="name=" + splt[1];
        alert(splt[1]);
    } catch (err) {
        txt = "Error Found\n\n";
        txt += "Description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
        txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
        alert(txt);
    }
}
</script>
```